# Twisted + Django as a daemon process plus Django + Apache

Tags: python, django, sqlite, twisted, daemon

I'm working on a distributed system where one process is controlling a hardware piece and I want it to be running as a service. My app is Django + Twisted based, so Twisted maintains the main loop and I access the database (SQLite) through Django, the entry point being a Django Management Command.

On the other hand, for user interface, I am writing a web application on the same Django project on the same database (also using Crossbar as websockets and WAMP server). This is a second Django process accessing the same database.

I'm looking for some validation here. Is anything fundamentally wrong to this approach? I'm particularly scared of issues with database (two different processes accessing it via Django ORM).

Comment: WebSockets and Apache generally don't go together, so not sure what you are thinking of doing in that respect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Indeed, I'm using Crossbar as Websockets (WAMP) server. Apache would be the web server for the Django webapp, although I'm currently using the development server, and I'd like to consider a more lightweight server to serve the Django app (but I also need CGI support for MapServer and WSGI support Django and MapProxy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that Django, like all WSGI-based web servers, almost *always* has multiple processes accessing the database. Because a single WSGI process can handle only one connection at a time, it's normal for servers to run multiple processes in parallel when they get any significant amount of traffic.

That doesn't mean there's no cause for concern. You have the database as if data might change between any two calls to it. Familiarize yourself with how [Django uses transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/) (default is autocommit mode, not atomic requests), and …

and oh, you said sqlite. Yeah, sqlite is probably not the best database to use when you need to write to it from multiple processes. I can imagine that might work for a single-user interface to a piece of hardware, but if you run in to any problems when adding the webapp, you'll want to trade up to a database server like postgresql.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can now validate this architecture too and it's working correctly. Your hint about WSGI already using multiple processes was very helpful. As a side note, SQLite is behaving correctly, of course under high loads it can block for too long, but that was expected.

Answer (score 1):

No there is nothing inherently wrong with that approach. We currently use a similar approach for a lot of our work.